# Is "described on the face" or "is described on the face" correct in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, passive-voice

> The passions *described* on the face of the statue survive the hands that made it.

Is this sentence correct or we have to say "is described"?
If it is correct, why did we not put "is described" to make it in passive voice?

Comment: Nadeen, I'm wondering if you mean inscribed ?

Comment: _Is described_ would be incorrect - the passive would be _which are described_ - but you need a different verb. _Depicted, portrayed_ for example?

Answer (score -1):

The active voice is preferred in English because it supplies the information more quickly so that the reader doesn't have to wait to understand the statement.  The active voice is also less wordy.